# Angular js ngroute is not working for a static HTML files

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

Am having a 6 html files in which am configuring the ngroute using angular js, each html file has images jquery slider and I have used the node express web server as server where it is running on 3000 port if I start my server and i open my browser and load the localhost:3000 am able to get the index.html file and its content if am navigating to other menu link am not able to get the content of that html file but its loading the preloader only, I post my HTML and angular js code below please do correct me any thing wrong

HTML

```
<div class="navbar-collapse pull-right nav-main-collapse collapse" ng-app="sam">
  <nav class="nav-main">
   <!--NOTE

    For a regular link, remove "dropdown" class from LI tag and "dropdown-toggle" class from the href.
    Direct Link Example:
    <li> <a href="#">HOME</a> </li>
    -->
    <ul id="topMain" class="nav nav-pills nav-main">
      <li class="active"><!-- HOME --> 
        <a  href="#index"> Home </a> </li>
      <li class="active"><!-- Instruction to Authors --> 
        <a  href="#author"> Instructions to Authors </a> </li>
      <li class="active"><!-- Manuscript Submission --> 
        <a  href="#manuscript">Manuscript Submission </a> </li>
      <li class="active"><!-- Contents --> 
        <a  href="#contents"> Contents </a> </li>
      <li class="active"><!-- Editorial Board --> 
        <a  href="#editorial"> Editorial Policy </a> </li>
      <li class="active"><!-- Contact Us --> 
        <a  href="#contact"> Contact Us </a> </li>
    </ul>
    <div ng-view></div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

script.js (angular js file)

```
var app = angular.module('sam', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
 $routeProvider.


       when('/index', {
        templateUrl: 'index.html'
      }).
       when('/author', {
        templateUrl: 'author.html'
      }).
      when('/contact', {
        templateUrl: 'contact.html'
      }). 
      when('/contents', {
        templateUrl: 'contents.html'
      }). 
      when('/editorial', {
        templateUrl: 'editorial.html'
      }).
       when('/manuscript', {
        templateUrl: 'manuscript.html'
      });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should link to `#/author` instead of `#author`

Comment: yeah I have added the #/ to the <a> </a> link tag its just loading the preloader only not the content

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have included ***angular-route.js*** in index.html

```
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
```

You can follow given link to ensure your code [this link](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07)

Comment: actually am getting it from cdn 

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular-route.js"> </script>

I think it is not the problem, problem is I dont know to route the folders in my project in node express web server

Comment: Please put your code of router here or you can update your question with addition of node express code

Comment: var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));

app.get(/^\/((?:[^\/]+\/?)+)\//, function(req, res) {
  res.send(req.params[0].split('/'));
});

app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("It's Started on PORT 3000");
});